# Place article_images inside a div only if there's more than 1?

Tags: matrix, conditionals

Pretty new to ExpressionEngine, so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I have a site where I want to use a slider on pages with more than one article image. The way I have it set up now works fine for these pages, but if there is a page with only 1 image, the image doesn't display because it's being hidden behind and off to the side of the content as if it were a slider image.

Basically, I want to make it so that if there is more than 1 image on the page, it will place the image code inside the "news_slider" div, but if there is only 1 image, it will just place that single image link without a div container. Here's the code:

```
{if article_images}
   <div id='news_slider'>
      {article_images}
         <img title="{img_title}" src="{img}" />
      {/article_images}
   </div>
{/if}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What field type is article_images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps there is a more elegant way, but this works:

```
{article_images}
    {if total_rows > "1" && row_count == "1"}
        <div id='news_slider'>
    {/if}
         <img title="{img_title}" src="{img}" />
    {if total_rows > "1" && row_count == total_rows}
        </div>
    {/if}
{/article_images}
```

Comment: This is what I was slowly typing on an iPad. :) But minus the opening {if articles_images} condition. That's not needed. Just {article_images} tag pair wrapper. If it's empty it won't print anything.

Comment: Ha ha, I wondered why you hadn't already nailed it, Stephen. You were encumbered! Max was actually typing at the same time, too. Good point about the outer conditional. I removed that.

Comment: Dang iPad! :) I get an assist.

Comment: Bingo! That worked a treat, thanks to everyone for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

With Matrix you can try next code:

```
{if article_images}
   {if {article_images_total_rows} > 1}<div id='news_slider'>{/if}
      {article_images}
         <img title="{img_title}" src="{img}" />
      {/article_images}
    {if {article_images_total_rows} > 1}</div>{/if}
{/if}
```